# C programming - Reverse a linked link by iterative method

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, reverse

I am trying to reverse a linked by iterative method. Magically, after watching tutorial and trying to recode myself, the program works successfully. However, when I review the code, I hit a question: in line 23, why we must use temp1->next instead of temp1? When traversing to the end of the linked list, which case we use the condition (the node != NULL)? In which case we use (the link of the node ! = NULL)?  I fully appreciate it if anyone can enlighten me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* Insert(struct Node* head, int data)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    //If the list is empty
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else //The list is not empty
    {
        struct Node* temp1 = head;
        while (temp1->next != NULL)
        {
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        temp1->next = temp;
    }
    return head;
}

void Print(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct Node* Reverse(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* *prev, *current, *next;
    current = head;
    prev = NULL;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    
    printf("Enter the length of the linked list you want to create: ");
    int length;
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("Enter the value you want to input: ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int x;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        head = Insert(head, x);
    }
  
    printf("Given linked list\n"); 
    Print(head); 
    head = Reverse(head);  
    printf("\nReversed linked list \n"); 
    Print(head); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you used `temp1 != NULL`, then `temp1` would be `NULL` after the loop, and you wouldn't be able to do the assignment `temp1->next = temp;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, inside the while condition, on line 23, you can notice that the program is using `temp1 = temp1->next`, if you change the condition to `temp1 != NULL` when it reaches the last element of linked list it'll collect trash from memory or even result in an error, because `NULL` don't have a next position.

So, you use `temp1 != NULL` if you are accessing the data inside the list and `temp1->next != NULL` if you are manipulating the next positions of the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Because `temp1->next` at the end of the linked list is `NULL`, however, the last node has data, if you use `temp1 == NULL` you would say that the last node is `NULL`, which is not the case. So you want to end the loop when the "pointer to the next node" is `NULL`, not when the next node is `NULL`.